# Cant able to save the data from a edittext

Tags: android, android-studio

So I am trying to make a library assistant app and what i want to do whenever i click on a button a dialogbox have to open and in that dialogbox i have to put a book name and it have to save on the database i implemented all the things but when click on a button a dialogbox will open and when i enter the name of the book and press ok.the error which i pasted below popping up

Error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                         Process: com.example.vishal.thadarinew, PID: 28712
                                                                            Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.vishal.thadarinew.Database.insertData(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.vishal.thadarinew.MainActivity$1$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:103)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

MainActivty.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private Button issueButton;
private Button reissueButton;
private Button returnButton;
Database myDb;
private EditText editQuantity;
public AlertDialogFragment malert;
String book;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient mClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    issueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.issueid);
    reissueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reissueid);
    returnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnid);

    issueButton();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

        }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        alertuserAboutError();
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_about) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

   return true;
}

public void alertuserAboutError() {
    final AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
}

public void issueButton(){
    issueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editQuantity = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            editQuantity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
                    .setMessage("Please Enter TIME")
                    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null)
                    .setView(editQuantity)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editQuantity.getText().toString());
                            if(isInserted == true)
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         dialog.dismiss();   // do nothing
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
        }
    });}}
```

Database.java

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Assistaant.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="Books";
public static final String COL_2="BNAME";
public static final String COL_3="DOI";
String pattern="dd-MM-yyyy";
Context con;

public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (BNAME TEXT,DOI TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public String today(){
    String date=new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(new Date());
    return date;
}


public boolean insertData(String bname) {


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,bname);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public void putreturn(int date){
    String strdate=date+"";
    try{
        FileOutputStream fileout=con.openFileOutput("date.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileout.write(strdate.getBytes());
        fileout.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException f){
        Toast.makeText(con,"Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(con,"Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}}
```

Comment: [NPE after NPE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718505/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-on-a-null-objec), please learn how to find the solution for NPE by yourself ... it's not so hard

Comment: Put this line in your onCreate method 
editQuantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editQuantity) ;

Comment: editQuantity was a editText from defaultAlertDialog i didnt created any xml layouts for alertdialogs